# Open file with special character in linux

Tags: linux, file, special-characters

I want to open file in linux  321716~`~Amstredam Hero - Jimmy to Worker'''s Comp Waiver.pdf´ in linux.   How can I open this file , i try ´ls - la 321716~`~Amstredam Hero - Jimmy to Worker'''s Comp Waiver.pdf

It's not working ,please help

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: Try using a glob. Narrow it down first to return only 1 file. For example, try first `ls *Waiver.pdf`. If it prints just the file you need, then open it. For example:`xpdf *Waiver.pdf`

Comment: Alternatively, use `find ... -exec ...`, like so: `find . -name '*Waiver*' -exec xpdf {} \;`

Answer (score 1):

I think your question was formatted in a way that messed with the styling, but you should be able to just enclose the filename with " " or possibly you could type the start of it and use * like `cat name*` and it would cat every file in that directory starting with "name"

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that most UNIX-like terminals have a kind of intellisense feature? You just start by typing some characters, you type <kbd>ESC</kbd> two times and the terminal tries to complete the filename. This should help you with your problem.